# Is there a version of LWEEncrypt in which probability of decryption error is zero?

Tags: lwe, probabilistic-encryption

Is there modification to LWE public key crypto-system which makes the decryption process is totally deterministic and does not affect security?

Answer (score 2):

When the parameters selected so the noise in the equation of the decrypted is smaller than q/4  for every element in the equation, this will decrypted correctly 100%. check this [survey](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JTdW5ryznp-dUBBjN12QbvWz9R41NDGU/view) and see section 2.3.2